# How to get all suggeted route text from ditrection pannel in google map in java script?

Tags: google-maps

When i enter source and destination it show me all suggested routes in direction panel. Let say it show me Route A, B and C. I want to get Route A road name, time and distance. Like "N5 Road 225 KM-about 3 hours 20 mins". I want to complete string. Please help me in this regard. Thanks

Comment: Parse the [directionsResult](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#DirectionsResult) , it contains all the data applied to the panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just get route summary by using following code:

```
var request = {
              origin: start,
              destination: end,
              provideRouteAlternatives: true,
              travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
          };
          directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
              if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

                    response.routes[0].summary;

                  directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

              }
          });
```